# Edge: Script70 error opening new window tab

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I am having an issue with Microsoft Edge browser (works fine on chrome, firefox, ie11).

Code:

```
    let win = window.open('', 'testWindow');
    win.document.open();
    win.document.write(var);
    win.document.close();
```

I am using this to open a new tab, write to it and print page. In Edge i am getting an error: Script70: permission denied on the `win.document.open();`. 
I have researched many similar issues with an iframe but have yet to find the cause of this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your code example which you can see in console in any browser.

You can try to modify your code like below will work with all browser including MS Edge.

```html
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var myWindow = window.open("", "TestWindow", "width=200,height=100");
      myWindow.document.write("<p>Hello World</p>");
      //myWindow.close();
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Note:- copy this code to your machine and than try to test it. If you try to run the code with stackOverFlow than it will give you an error.

Comment: What syntax error? On closer look - my issue is more related to ```window.open()``` triggering the popup blocker in Edge when I need to open a new tab without interference

Comment: You have some permission related issue on your end cause Script 70 error. If I run your exact code on my machine with multiple browsers than it returns this error. https://i.postimg.cc/ZnSMWX7D/67.png You are trying to write on window using 'Win.write(var)' but you cannot write to window. this is your syntax error.  you can write to document as I suggested you in my answer.

Comment: I see, it was just a typo on my part. I did have ```document``` in my code. Updated the original post. thanks. My issue still persists though